# SpelEvaluationException: EL1005E: Type cannot be found in Springboot 3.2.0

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-boot-test, spring-el, spring-boot-starter

When upgrading springboot to 3.2.0, the error `SpelEvaluationException: EL1005E: Type cannot be found` happens.

This has happened from previous springboot version but it has been fixed. 
But lately when springboot 3.2.0 was released, this happened again.

I got this error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1005E: Type cannot be found 'co.lib.util.FaceUtils'
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.support.StandardTypeLocator.findType(StandardTypeLocator.java:128)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ExpressionState.findType(ExpressionState.java:181)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.TypeReference.getValueInternal(TypeReference.java:70)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.CompoundExpression.getValueRef(CompoundExpression.java:61)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.CompoundExpression.getValueInternal(CompoundExpression.java:97)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.SpelNodeImpl.getValue(SpelNodeImpl.java:114)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpression.getValue(SpelExpression.java:273)
    at org.springframework.context.expression.StandardBeanExpressionResolver.evaluate(StandardBeanExpressionResolver.java:167)
```

Basically, I suspect it happened in this code:

```
class FaceState {
  @Value("#{T(co.FaceUtils).parseDate('${git.commit.time:}')}")
  private CommitDateTime commitTime;
}
```

Anybody at least guide me on how to fix this?..

Comment: Not a specific solution to this problem, but general advice. Try separating some of the `magic` operations in the `@Value` part. Maybe you could parse the date in a setter or helper method. So you could also implement a better error handling in case of an unsupported date pattern.

Comment: Maybe you could try to use the class name with packages in the Spel string and see what spring says.

Comment: @Easterwood thanks, but it seems to be a bug in 3.2.0,,,I found this reference https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/31668